# Strange behaviour when intentionally assigning `i` value greater than INT_MAX

Tags: c

When I assign `i` value greater than `INT_MAX` in this code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{

   int i;
   i=INT_MAX+3;

   printf("%d \n",INT_MAX);  //INT_MAX = 2147483647

   if(i>INT_MAX) 
     {     
         printf("OVERFLOW");
     }
  else 
    {
         printf("%d",i);    
    }   
     return 0;
}
```

So in this as `i=INT_MAX+3;` then condition is true and `overflow` should be printed but it prints some `negative value`. Is it undefined behaviour ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, signed integer overflow has undefined behavior in C.
2. `i > INT_MAX` is never true for any `int i`. How can you have an `int` greater than the maximum possible `int`?